# Why refresh endpoint return new tokens when i use old refresh token?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, bcrypt

Hello i use these two libraries from npm: `bcrypt` and `jsonwebtoken`.

I create `/refresh-token` endpoint and want to generate new pair of access and refresh token. So I send refresh token to endpoint and check it (if is not null), get user from database from data saved in token claims and compare refresh token from request to hashed refresh token stored in database. If `isMatch` is true I generate new pair of tokens and create hash from refresh token using `bcrypt`. Next I save this hash into database and return new pair to user. But when i send a this same refresh token as before i still get new pair, even more if i send access token instead of refresh tokens `isMatch` return true and i get new pair of tokens. Hash is created from different jwt (different strings) so how it's possible to always get true in compare?

```js
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { User } from '../entities/user.model';
import { getRepository } from 'typeorm';
import { InternalServerException } from '../exceptions/exceptions';

interface AccessPayload {
  email: string;
  role: string;
};

export class JwtTokenProvider {

  private readonly jwtSecret: string = process.env.JWT_SECRET as string;

  generateAccessTokens = async (user: User) => {
    if (!user) {
      throw new InternalServerException('Failed to generate JWT Token - User is null');
    };
    const accessPayload: AccessPayload = {email: user.email, role: user.role as string};
    const accessToken: string = jwt.sign(accessPayload, this.jwtSecret, {
      expiresIn:  process.env.TOKEN_EXP_TIME as string
    });
    const refreshToken: string = jwt.sign(accessPayload, this.jwtSecret, {
      expiresIn: process.env.REFRESH_EXP_TIME as string
    });
    this.saveRefreshToken(user, refreshToken);
    return { accessToken, refreshToken };
  };

  getUserFromToken = async (token: string): Promise<User | undefined>  => {
    const tokenPayload = await jwt.verify(token, this.jwtSecret) as AccessPayload;
    return await getRepository(User).findOne({ email: tokenPayload.email }, { relations: ['groupScope'] });
  };

  compareRefreshTokens = async (plainToken: string, hashToken: string): Promise<boolean> => {
    return await bcrypt.compare(plainToken, hashToken);
  };

  private saveRefreshToken = async (user: User, refreshToken: string): Promise<any> => {
    user.refreshToken = await this.encodeRefreshToken(refreshToken);
    await getRepository(User).save(user);
  };

  private encodeRefreshToken = async (refreshToken: string): Promise<string> => {
    return await bcrypt.hash(refreshToken, 12);
  }
};
```

```js
public refreshToken = async (request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
     const requestToken = request.body.refresh_token as string;
      if (!requestToken) {
        return next(new BadRequestException('Refresh token cannot be empty'));
      }
      const user = await this.jwtProvider.getUserFromToken(requestToken);
      if (!user) {
        return next(new AuthorizedException('Cannot get user from token'));
      }
      const isMatch = await this.jwtProvider.compareRefreshTokens(requestToken, user.refreshToken);
      if(!isMatch) {
        return next(new AuthorizedException('Refresh token is incorrect'));
      }
      const { accessToken, refreshToken } = await this.jwtProvider.generateAccessTokens(user);
      response.status(200).send({ accessToken, refreshToken });
    } catch (error) {
        return next(new Error(error.message));
      };
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [bcrypt repo page](https://github.com/dcodeIO/bcrypt.js#security-considerations):

> The maximum input length is 72 bytes (note that UTF8 encoded characters use up to 4 bytes) and the length of generated hashes is 60 characters.

It's means that only the first 72 bytes of a string are used. Any extra bytes are ignored when matching refresh tokens (note that this is not the first 72 characters). Because of the 72 bytes are matched, you get a success response when using an old token.

A workaround is to hash the string first using SHA-256, and then use bcrypt.

```js
import { createHash } from 'crypto';

const hash = createHash('sha256').update(user.refreshToken).digest('hex');
user.refreshToken = bcrypt.hashSync(hash, salt);
```

And then (maybe in another file):

```js
import { createHash } from 'crypto';

const hash = createHash('sha256').update(refreshToken).digest('hex');
if (await bcrypt.compare(hash, user.refreshToken)) {
  // refresh tokens are matched!
}
```